# How to get a low dimensional rank of non-negative factorization matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, pca, algebra, svd

I have a big matrix

```
X = numpy.random.rand(1000, 1000)
```

using sklearn.decomposition I factorized the matrix such as:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF

model = NMF(n_components=1, init='random', random_state=0)

W = model.fit_transform(X)

H = model.components_
```

Now I want to find the low dim rank of W.
How could I find the rank of W?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the rank of NMF matrices, the big matrix contains noises, which should be removed using a singular value threshold formula. After thresholding, it will be easier to get non-zero values of the NMF matrix.